# Python: Selenium WebDriver find_elements_by_class_name

Tags: python, selenium

I want to select all the rows in a table that have class name either `TCP_RowOdd` or `TCP_RowEven`.
Currently, I am doing it like this

`oddRows = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("TCP_RowOdd")`

`evenRows = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("TCP_RowEven")`

Is there an OR clause that can be used here to do it in a single query.

Answer (score 9):

There are multiple ways to that, I prefer the *CSS selector*:

```
rows = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".TCP_RowOdd,.TCP_RowEven")
```

The comma in the selector means "or".

---

Or, we can grab all elements having a class that *starts with* `TCP_Row`:

```
rows = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("[class^=TCP_Row]")
```

Comment: Nice to know about the comma :)